# Correct way to build forms

Tags: html, css, forms, css-tables

I'm currently building a signup form and I find myself resorting to tables in order to align things properly e.g. [the MySpace equivalent](https://www.myspace.com/signup) where I would use a colspan to achieve the even spacing between the three birthday text areas and the other text inputs. Is this going against conventions and should I be looking into more advanced CSS?

Comment: Since you're linking to MySpace, why not take a look at their html/css and see how they do it..?

Comment: Wouldn't this kind of question produce largely subjective answers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should drop the table all together and use more CSS.
You could look into this: http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/css-forms.shtml

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using Divs, floats and margins and not tables

Answer (score 1):

It is generally against conventions. You should be using CSS to position your elements here. The CSS needn't be advanced though. E.g.

```
<div class="field-name"><label for="birthday">Birthday</label></div>
<div class="field"><input class="text-field" name="birthday" type="text" /></div>
```

CSS can be added to these elements.

```
.field-name{ float:left; width:100px; }
.field{float:left; width:150px;}
```

This should then position your fields next to each other. I'm not sure of your layout, but this is a simple example really. You can remove the divs as well if needed and change the CSS accordingly. I hope this helps.